# How wait that Run (from OperatingSystem library) is performed before to do the next step?

Tags: robotframework

I have one test case (`TC1`). This test case call with the command `Run    robot -t TC2 mytestsuite.robot` another test case (`TC2`).

However, `TC2` is performed only at the end of `TC1`, not at the moment where it is called.

We can see that on logs. Call is done at `10:21:55.870` but the command is executed only at `10:23:21.463`.

The algorithm looks like:

```
Some actions
Run    robot -t TC2 mytestsuite.robot
Some actions 2
```

Here `Some actions 2` are performed before `Run    robot -t TC2 mytestsuite.robot`. How wait that the run is performed before to do the next step?

Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I can't duplicate your results, and what you describe seems impossible. The `Run` keyword will not return until the command it is running has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put called test cases in another project.